# How does research contribute to teaching, and vice versa?

Tags: research-process, teaching

If research is related to teaching then research could have a direct contributions to  teaching.  However, if research is not directly related to teaching, then how can each of them contribute to the other?

Comment: Hello, could you please maybe provide a bit more background? What is your field and what is the position type - professor, TA, independent researcher (think French CR1 at CNRS), ...?

Comment: Hi, I guess disciplines and positions won't make a big difference. Assume computing or engineering major applying for assistant professor position.

Comment: It seems like the question in the body of your post is different from the one in your title; specifically, the question in the body asks how you should answer the question in the title (when applying for an assistant professor position, as I gather from your comment.)  You should answer it truthfully: how _does_ your research contribute to your teaching and vice versa?  No one here can answer that for you.

Comment: @TrevorWilson my teaching is not directly related to my research, so this creates some confusion on how to answer such question.

Comment: Maybe you could show that they are indirectly related somehow, or you could say how you plan to relate the two in the future.

Comment: The only good answer depends on how **your** research informs **your** teaching and vice versa.

Comment: @JeffE Sure, but there are always general answers that a graduate student may not think of and can extend.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally, I struggle coming up with good teaching materials (lecture notes, homework questions, et cetera). I had lots of teachers that were either way too abstract where abstraction wasn't necessary, or gave really wacky examples that didn't have much basis in real life, and I silently vowed not to do that to my own students. One way that I've found to present real-life and relevant material is to draw upon my research. For example, if I'm lecturing about a particular biological system that I study, I might walk the class through a particular experiment that I ran to test an aspect of the system. I find that students feel these lectures are the most interesting, and they seem to grasp the material better than if I gave a "standard" lecture.

On the flip side, I always get 1-2 questions per semester where I don't know the answer, and it turns out no one else in my field does either. As such, the questions I get while teaching are a source of research questions that I may attempt to answer. If I actually think the question can be answered, I almost always invite the student or students who posed the question to help me with the research, which is also another way teaching impacts research (i.e., I expose more people to what research is, and I get help doing it).

Comment: +1 for "If I actually think the question can be answered, I almost always invite the student or students who posed the question to help me with the research"